# Is there a CLI client for Skype chat conversations?

Tags: windows, terminal, skype, instant-messaging, command-line

I'm looking for an interface to Skype that I can run in a CLI on windows (`cmd.exe`). All I really need is access to my IM conversations. Is there such a beast? Or is there an API for creating such a beast?

Comment: What do you mean with "access to my IM conversations"? Do you mean logs/history or do you mean chatting?

Comment: I mean chatting. In the skype chat application, I have a list of conversations, which contains not just a log/history, but also works like a chat room...

Answer (score 4):

The only solution I have for you is Linux-based. Finch is the CLI version of Pidgin/Adium/formerly GAIM.  This [link](http://eion.robbmob.com/) is the plugin that might work.  Keep in mind that, despite running in a terminal with ncurses, Skype must run concurrently (I am pretty sure they STILL have not released their chat API).  You might be able to re-compile this plug-in for Cygwin, but that will be a hassle.  Contact the plug-in developer to find out for sure.

Comment: there *is* a COM (ActiveX) interface for skype on windows. I was able to hack into it with python really easy, but never got round to writing me a client...

Comment: @Daren Thomas That sounds very cool.  Do you know where I can find documentation on this COM component?

Comment: check out Skype4COM here: http://developer.skype.com/accessories